# How to close a popup light box

Tags: javascript, ajax

This is my code. Here Iam closing the popupbox using 'x'. But I want it to be closed by clicking on any radio button.

HTML:

```
<a href = "javascript:void()" onclick = "document.getElementById('light_<?php echo $vid;?>').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block';"><span>Book now</a> <!--<div class="disp"><p>-->
<div id="light_<?php echo $vid;?>" class="white_content">
    <label>Email:</label>
    <?=$vehicle->Email; ?>
    </p><p>
    <label>Mobile:</label>
    <?=$vehicle->Mobile; ?></p>
    <p>
        <form id="form_<?php echo $vid;?>" name="form1" method="post" action="">
            <?php //echo $_REQUEST['email'];?>
            <p>
                <input type="hidden" name="vehicleid" value="<?php echo $vid;?>" id="vehicleid" />
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1_<?php echo $vid;?> " value="1" id="bstatus<?php echo $vid;?>" onClick="idForm(<?php echo $vid;?>)" />
                    Conform
                </label>
                <br />
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1<?php echo $vid;?>" value="0" id="bstatus1<?php echo $vid;?>" onClick="idForm(<?php echo $vid;?>)" />
                    Not Conform
                </label>
                <br />
            </p>
        </form>
        <a href = "javascript:void()" onclick = "document.getElementById('light_<?php echo $vid;?>').style.display='none';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none'"><b>X</b></a>
    </div>
    <div id="fade" class="black_overlay"></div>
</div></span>
```

JS:

```
function idForm(str) {
    var light = 'light_' + str;
    var fade = 'fade' + str; 
    document.getElementById(light).style.display = 'none'; 
    document.getElementById(fade).style.display = 'none';
    var confirmval = 'bstatus' + str;
    var unconfirmval = 'bstatus1' + str;
    if (document.getElementById(confirmval).checked) {
        var selectvalue = document.getElementById(confirmval).value;
    }
```

Comment: Your JS code is missing, it seems that you had a copy/paste issue.

Comment: actually it dnt allow in question, so have to write it in comments

Comment: You have several HTML errors: for example `<span>Book now</a>`. Inline JS is someone's nightmare - it is very difficult to read it. Mix of HTML and PHP is not very readable thing too.

Comment: did you solve the problem @teja123